# Click an image to bring up a bigger image in a small popup window

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a function where the user can click an image and a bigger one will load in a small popup window. I already have the bigger image in the system so it merely needs to load the image but in a window the right size!

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into using one of many js lightbox solutions
http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ for example

Comment: Implemented this, my first use of jQuery. How simple was that! There must be so many other jQuery options to use!

Answer (score 2):

Look into [window.open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That will let you open a new window of a specified height and width, you just need to do something like:

```
window.open("<?php echo $url; ?>", "_blank", 
            "height=<?php echo $height;?>  width=<?php echo $width; ?>")
```

You can get the image size in PHP with [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Went with the jQuery option but this was helpful too :)

Answer (score 0):

I [created a responsive javascript only lightbox](http://jslightbox.felixhagspiel.de/) (no jquery needed) where you can pass links to the bigger image. So your thumbnail HTML should look like this, where your thumbnail-picture goes into the `src` attribute and the link to the bigger picture goes into the `data-jslghtbx` attribute:

`<img class="jslghtbx-thmb" src="img/lightbox/thumbnail-picture.jpg" alt="" data-jslghtbx="img/big-picture.jpg">`

You can also use the gallery function via the `data-jslghtbx-group` attribute to show multiple pictures, but be sure to hide all image elements (except the thumbnail which triggers the lightbox) via `display: none;`. Visit [github for full documentation](https://github.com/felixhagspiel/jsOnlyLightbox). Hope this helps!